# What are the differences between offensive and defensive assists?

Tags: overwatch

When I look at the statistics for various heroes under my Career Profile, I notice that "Offensive Assists" and "Defensive Assists" are listed.

What are offensive and defensive assists, and what are the differences between them?

Comment: Can't find really good information anywhere to cite in an answer, but most people seem to think that you get a defensive assist if your healing/shield/armor lets somebody kill somebody, and an offensive assist if you boost their damage while they kill somebody.

Comment: Just confirmed this in a custom game.

Answer (score 20):

Assists in Overwatch are a bit different than assists in other shooters and are largely a support stat. Assists are counted when you contribute in some way to a kill/elimination without dealing damage. Mercy, Lucio, Ana, and Zenyatta (and S:76, I believe) can get *defensive* assists by providing healing to an attacker while they are dealing damage to a target. Mercy and Zenyatta can get *offensive* assists by providing damage boosts, either through Mercy's Cadeceus Staff alternate fire or Zenyatta's Orb of Discord. Lucio can get offensive assists with Speed Boost, though he must Amp his songs to get the assists in both cases (Healing Boost for defensive and Speed Boost for offensive).

As Zenyatta is the only hero who can qualify for both assists at the same time, I did some testing and it seems that defensive assists take priority over offensive assists so if an ally with Harmony kills an enemy tagged with Discord, you get a defensive assist rather than an offensive assist.

Comment: I seem to remember you can only get defensive assists as Lucio whilst Amping it Up, and you can get offensive assists whilst doing the same with the speed boost on.

Comment: Yeah, just jumped into a custom game and confirmed this.